# How to align the footer at the bottom center in HTML

Tags: html

I want to align the footer at the bottom center of the page but the code below doesnt work. Could you please tell me what changes should i make ?

```
<style type="text/css">  
  #footer {  
   bottom : 2;  
   height : 40px;  
   margin-top : 40px;  
   text-align: center;  
   vertical-align: middle;  

  }  
</style>  
<div id="footer">Terms and Conditions </div>
```

Comment: You need sticky footer

Comment: By "align" do you mean to center the #footer or text alignment?

Comment: Can you create fiddle? and also try with adding `clear:both;margin:0 auto;` in `#footer`. see http://jsfiddle.net/z2Amq/ it already working .

Comment: `margin:0 auto;` should do the trick his footer is div

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/n9r9J/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first **`bottom` value should be in `px` or `%`**. Check this [CSS : BOTTOM](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/bottom) , and it will work only if you **combined it with any `position` property**, Check this [CSS:POSITION](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/position)

**And if you want place the footer always at the bottom of your page you can use a combination of `position:fixed` and `bottom:<value>`.**

**And finally set the div `width:100%` to make it occupy the whole width of the browser window**
like this,

```
 #footer {  
   bottom : 2px;  
   height : 40px;  
   margin-top : 40px;  
   text-align: center;  
   vertical-align: middle; 
   position:fixed;
   width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This code:

```
  <style type="text/css">  
  #footer {  
   bottom : 2; 
   padding-bottom: 0; 
   height : 40px;  
   margin-top : 40px; 
   margin: auto;
   width: 50%;
   text-align: center;  
  }  
</style>  
<div id="footer">Terms and Conditions </div>
```

You can change the width according to your wish

Answer (score 0):

To center most things you need to define a width, and then let auto-margins take over the rest.

```
<style type="text/css">  
  #footer {  
   bottom : 2;  
   height : 40px;   
   text-align: center;  
   vertical-align: middle;


   width:950px;
   margin:40px auto 0;  

  }  
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#footer {  
     height: 100px;
     margin-top: -50px;
     position: fixed;
     bottom:0;
     width: 100%;
     z-index: 1;
     text-align:center;
  }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wMg7A/)