# How to position copyright footer into the center bottom of the footer?

Tags: html, css

How can I position my copyright `footer` into the center bottom of my footer without setting a padding? Is there any "correct" way of doing it?

**HTML**

```
<footer class="footer">
    <div class="footerContainer">
        <p class="copyright">© GROUP TITLE 2015</p>
    </div>
</footer>
```

**CSS**

```
footer.footer {
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #333333;
}

p.copyright {
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-size: 0.7em;
}
```

Help, please.

Comment: you have two `</div>` closing tags. Is that a typo, or in your code? These should be `</footer>` closing tags or vice versa.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/single-page.html#the-footer-element `footer` can't contain `footer`.

Comment: Oh, just noticed that typo, fixed it. @Ian

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that at all. @zzzzBov

Comment: Define "into the end" succinctly as it pertains to the layout. An illustration will suffice if words fail.

Comment: Ment `bottom`@zer00ne

Comment: Then Baldrani's should answer should work unless you needed it centered as well.

Comment: In the future, you should reproduce the relevant code in a snippet (icon on the editor's toolbar that looks like a page with brackets), [jsFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net), [PenCode.io](http://pencode.io), or [Plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co)

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20042474/how-to-align-the-footer-at-the-bottom-center-in-html

Comment: @zer00ne I don't think its a dupe. The OP wants certain text to be centered on the bottom from within the footer. Not the footer itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this CSS:

```
<style>
    footer {
        position: relative;
        height: 300px;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #333333;
    }

    p.copyright {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        color: #fff;
        line-height: 40px;
        font-size: 0.7em;
        text-align: center;
        bottom:0;
    }
</style>
```

And adjust your HTML to:

```
<footer>
    <p class="copyright">© GROUP TITLE 2015</p>
</footer>
```

And here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j7u4sea4/).

Comment: Thanks, really helped me.

Answer (score 3):

This should work.

```
footer {
    position: relative;
}
.copyright{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: `.footerContainer` `position: relative`? Or delete that first.

Answer (score 0):

do you realy need the footer and the footer container?

well doesnt matter, do you want it on the end of the page or allways in the bottom of the visible page?

for the end of the page:

```
 CSS:

 footer {
       position: absolute;
       bottom:0; 
 }
```

if you want it in the bottom of the screen (allways)

```
 CSS:

 footer {
       position: fixed;
       bottom:0; 
 }
```

you may learn a lot of these basics in [www.w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp) (directed to the position property page).

**and abviously you have to close what you open..**

Comment: Position isn't an attribute. It's a property

Comment: sorry about that big mistake.

Comment: For Christ's Sake, who's so downvote happy? Barreto's answer is correct. Give someone the courtesy by giving them an opportunity to rectify a mistake before you downvote.